# How to insert empty string in DynamoDB using the output of a Lambda in Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, jsonpath, aws-step-functions, aws-lex

I'm trying to save the output of a Lambda which calls Lex to DynamoDB using Step Functions.

The `intentName` in a Lex response is sometimes **null** (unknown). The problem is that in the state (task) that saves the response to DynamoDB, because of this empty string I get an error from DynamoDB.

Is there any workaround, maybe using JsonPath or the state machine diagram of the Step Function, in order to insert **null** or maybe no insert that specific property in DynamoDB?

Here is the JSON for the state machine:

```
{
  "StartAt": "ProcessLex",
  "States": {
    "ProcessLex": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:<Region>:<Account Id>:function:getIntent",
      "ResultPath": "$.lexResult",
      "Next": "ChoiceIfIntent"
    },
    "SaveToDynamo": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:putItem",
      "Parameters": {
        "TableName": "MyTable",
        "Item": {
          "dateTime": {
            "S.$": "$.dateTime"
          },
          "intentName": {
            "S.$": "$.lexResult.intentName"
          },
          "analysis": {
            "M.$": "$.lexResult.sentimentResponse"
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    },
    "Comprehend": {
      "Comment": "To be implemented later",
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    },
    "ChoiceIfIntent": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {

            "Variable": "$.lexResult.intentName",
            "StringGreaterThanEquals": "",

          "Next": "SaveToDynamo"
        }        
      ],
        "Default": "Comprehend"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's not longer a problem since May 18, 2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the *null* value, the problem is that in DynamoDB with the PutItem Api you **cannot** insert empty strings.

I know this is frustrating but the quickest solution is to replace **""** with **NULL**.

The solution that I prefer is to set the *convertEmptyValue* to true in your DynamoDb client settings.

```js
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ convertEmptyValues: true })
```

UPDATE

Since yesterday, DynamoDB supports empty values for string!
Take a look [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-empty-values-for-non-key-string-and-binary-attributes-in-dynamodb-tables/?sc_channel=sm&sc_campaign=DB_Blog&sc_publisher=TWITTER&sc_country=DynamoDB&sc_geo=GLOBAL&sc_outcome=awareness&trk=ddbemptyvalues_051820_TWITTER&sc_category=Amazon%20DynamoDB&linkId=88894636).

Comment: Thanks you!.

I've seen this solution, but the problem is that I'm using **Step Functions**, meaning that the output from Lex is saved in DynamoDB using states, I don't have direct access to the DynamoDB SDK.

I'll put the JSON for the state machine above.

Comment: @eldercookie take a look at the link that I've added in the answer. Now your issue should be solved!

Comment: Thank you very much!. I'm going to try it and tell how it went.

Comment: Apparently they fixed it on May 18, 2020

Comment: @DimaTisnek as I wrote in the answer